# Returning Null in Rust function

Tags: null, rust

how can i return Null in Rust function?

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct NodeValue {
    id: String,
    parent: String,
    children: Vec<NodeValue>,
}

impl NodeValue {
    fn find_parent(&self, id: &mut String) -> &NodeValue {
        if self.id == *id {
            println!("{},{}", self.id, id);
            return self;
        }
        for child in &self.children {
            println!("{:?}", child);
            let res = child.find_parent(id);
            return res;
        }

        return null; //return null
    }
}

fn main() {
    let root = NodeValue {
        id: "#".to_string(),
        parent: String::from("root"),
        children: vec![],
    };

    let id = "1";
    let mut parent = "#";
    let mut parent_node = root.find_parent(&mut parent);
    let node1 = NodeValue {
        id: "2".to_string(),
        parent: "1".to_string(),
        children: vec![],
    };
    parent_node.children.push(node1);
}
```

[my code in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d6c0ba85cf62e7ab0b68d2e0cf1ce10e)

Comment: Why are you taking a `&mut String` in your `find_parent` function? A `&str` would be a better solution here. I recommend you to read [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/) which helps you to learn the rust language, because it seems, that you haven't read it yet.

Comment: By the way, the method `find_parent` is logically incorrect and is not doing what is expected.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot return `null` in Rust, because there is no such concept in the language. Instead you should use [`Option<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html):

```
fn find_parent(&self, id: &mut String) -> Option<&NodeValue> {
    if self.id == *id {
        println!("{},{}", self.id, id);
        return Some(self);
    }

    //This loop is pointless, I've kept it because it's in your original code
    for child in &self.children {
        println!("{:?}", child);
        return child.find_parent(id);
    }

    None
}
```

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering. I was using JNI and needed to return a null to Java. You can use `std::ptr::null_mut()` or `std::ptr::null()` (as required) in those particular instances for FFI.